Erro ao Percorrer linhas com WHILE
 $countRows = EntityContacts::getContact(null,null,'campaign',null,'contacts.id_campaign= campaign.id GROUP BY id_campaign',null,'id_campaign, COUNT(id_contact) AS qtd');
    while ($rowQtd = $countRows->fetchObject(EntityContacts::class))
    {
        $rowsQtd = $rowQtd->qtd;
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($rowQtd->qtd);
        //echo "</pre>";exit;
    }
    //excecutando sql dentro do phpmyadmin
    SELECT id_campaign, COUNT(id_contact) AS qtd FROM contacts   INNER JOIN campaign  ON contacts.id_campaign= campaign.id GROUP BY id_campaign
     id_campaign    qtd     
       35           2
       36           3
    


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
